# how to bring network up at boot time in linux

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, boot

I am working on an embedded linux system, my aim is to activate ethernet interface at boot time. I am using u-boot as bootloader. I passed ip= and eth= u-boot environment variables to the linux kernel as bootargs and configured linux kernel as IP:kernel level autoconfiguration , enabled. However, that didn't bring the network interface up, as "ifconfig eth0 up" do.

So, I am wondering if it is possible to instruct linux kernel to activate eth0 interface without resorting to user space scripts (ifup and ifconfig)?

Comment: I think making `ONBOOT=yes` in this file will solve your problem, file path is `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the Linux kernel can activate eth0 interface without resorting to user space scripts.
You can use the `ip=` kernel boot parameter to initialize the network interface with a static IP address, for example:

```
    ip=192.168.1.100:::255.255.255.0:myboard:eth0:on
```

Of course, the *eth0* interface cannot be enabled until drivers have been initialized/installed (as indicated by the freeing of the `__init` section of memory).
Here's the system log to show when the network interface becomes active:

```
eth0: link down
IP-Config: Complete:
      device=eth0, addr=192.168.1.100, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=255.255.255.255,
    host=myboard, domain=, nis-domain=(none),
    bootserver=255.255.255.255, rootserver=255.255.255.255, rootpath=
Freeing init memory: 564K
remounting / read-write... done.
mounting /proc... done.
mounting /sys... done.
Creating device nodes manually, running /sbin/makenodes-2.6
eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
Done.
mounting /home... MTDSB: dev_name "/dev/mtdblock3"
```

Complete details on the syntax of the `ip=` boot parameter are in [Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt).  Ignore the fact that the original purpose of this capability was to facilitate a networked root filesystem.

> I passed ip= and eth= u-boot environment variables to the linux kernel as bootargs

`eth=` is not a valid boot parameter, and is probably ignored by the kernel.
BTW If you're using Atmel's `macb.c` driver, then ensure that U-Boot installs the MAC address for the PHY for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and valuable info. I am not using any of the autoconfiguration protocols: bootp, dhcp or rarp. So, the last parameter would be "off". Also, I am using ramdisk (not nfs) and macb.c driver.

I have a u-boot variable called ethaddr that has this value: 00:05:F4:11:22:33. Is this what you meant regarding u-boot to load MAC address for the PHY? How to make sure u-boot installed the MAC?

Comment: I've used that "autoconf" set to "on" simply to enable networking, mostly UDP traffic for the embedded app, and not NFS etc.  Like you, I didn't want to have to use an *init* script.  Yes, the *ethaddr* has to written to the PHY, and U-Boot has to properly initialize the PHY if you expect networking using `macb`.  Please read Atmel's Nicolas Ferre confirm my remarks in http://www.at91.com/forum/viewtopic.php/f,12/t,21030/  If Ethernet is working in U-Boot, then Linux can also.