# Set hostname subsequent to each boot?

Tags: networking, hostname

I'm looking into the possibility of setting hostname on my Arch Linux system (laptop) each time I boot the machine. I don't use any display manager, btw, but simply boot (using syslinux) to a terminal login prompt. After logging in at the command line, I then run `startx` to start the GUI.

What I have in mind would be running a script once the terminal login process is complete, a script that would query whether or not I'd like to modify the hostname. Answering "no" would allow the hostname set in /etc/hostname to be used, while answering "yes" would run `hostname somehostname` (or `hostnamectl set-hostname 'somehostname'` or `echo somehostname > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname`). So, to be clear, ideally the script would be triggered after I've entered my login credentials at the tty but before I run the command `startx` from the tty under which I've logged on.

I've already experimented with creating a script to do this. So far it is not being triggered only at log-in as I'd hoped, but every time I open a terminal (I've tried triggering it from ~/.bash_profile). But before trying to resolve that issue I need to first determine whether doing this sort of thing is advisable/possible. Input on that will be appreciated.

PS The reason I'm looking into doing this is because I sometimes use a wifi network that blocks the port I use to connect to my home machine. I've therefore taken, when using that network, to tunneling traffic to my home computer via port 443 which is open on that network and which works. But I do find myself getting booted offline at times--I suspect because traffic I'm routing via port 443 may look suspicious to the network admins. So I'm experimenting with MAC spoofing and/or hostname modification to see if that might prevent me from getting disconnected.

Comment: You can specify a hostname *"on boot"* through the kernel command line, i.e. the `ip=...` parameter.  See https://superuser.com/questions/502793/how-to-bring-network-up-at-boot-time-in-linux/503086#503086 .  U-Boot has "scripts" and variable substitution to make this easy.  I don't know the capabilities of GRUB or other boot programs.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm a syslinux user myself. What sorts of systems are using u-boot these days?

Comment: I'd guess SBCs - my orange pi runs uboot

Comment: There are many hooks to run at boot or when starting X11 but this sounds like you want it to happen when you actually log in to your X11 session. Depending on the precise setup, the session manager will look for an executable script like `.xsession` and run whatever commands are contained in that. The precise filename also depends on the version of your OS, and if you use a desktop environment like Gnome or KDE, it will offer different or additional hooks which probably make more sense to use.

Comment: Actually I want this script to be triggered before X starts. Rather, my preference is that it gets triggered immediately after I log in at the tty. I envision running startx after the script runs, should I decide to use the GUI in the session under discussion (just added clarifications to that effect to my OP). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround with the least development (as you already have written some form of a script) is to make that script write a temporary file in a `tmpfs` filesystem and check for its existence.

**1.** You start the machine and you log in. The script gets executed via `bash_profile`. The script checks for the existence of `/tmp/hostname_changed`, and if it doesn't exist - it prompts you if you'd like a hostname change.
**2.** You answer yes, the script changes the hostname, and then it creates the file `/tmp/hostname_changed` (this file can be empty).
**3.** Now when you open a terminal, the script will check if the temporary file exists, and since it was already created, the script will exit without asking you anything.

A simple bash example:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /tmp/hostname_changed ]; then
    # prompt for hostname change
    # if yes:
    # change hostname
    echo > /tmp/hostname_changed
    # if not, exit
fi
```